# Number of k-multisets satisfy some conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to know the formula(s) for the number of k-multisets if each element appear at most j times with j = 1 and j >= k. My thought was since there are two choices for number of repetition (0 and 1), the number will be $2^k$.

Comment: What's definition of $k$-multiset?

Comment: Still waiting for definition...

Comment: It’s an unordered k-set with repetition allowed. Sorry for the late response